# Kendo Scheduler Refresh after updating datasource

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-scheduler

I have following example (modified original demo from Kendo Scheduler):

http://dojo.telerik.com/AkIGO

In this example I create a data array with two events which are displayed properly on the scheduler view on the right side.

```
var data = [{ TaskID: 0, OwnerID: 1, Title: "Bowling tournament 6", Start: "2013-06-10T10:30:00", End: "2013-06-10T11:30:00", IsAllDay: false},{ TaskID: 1, OwnerID: 2, Title: "Golf", Start: "2013-06-11T10:30:00", End: "2013-06-11T11:30:00", IsAllDay: false}];
```

I have included a button, which event I catch and then extend this "data" array with one more element like this:

```
data.push({ TaskID: 2, OwnerID: 3, Title: "New Event", Start: "2013-06-12T10:30:00", End: "2013-06-12T11:30:00", IsAllDay: false});
console.log(data);
```

The console.log of the array confirms the addition. I hence call the following refresh code:

```
$("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler").refresh();
```

...which does not update my scheduler view on the right to include the new event (created for wednesday 6/12).

I have also tried:

```
$('#scheduler').data('kendoScheduler').dataSource.read();
```

but this results in an error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The command to update the current view of the scheduler is :

```
var scheduler = $('#scheduler').data('kendoScheduler');
scheduler.view(scheduler.view().name);
```

Comment: @Silvanmidix : The scheduler does not show the first 2 events "Bowling Tournament 6" and "Golf"  which is supposed to be seen when scheduler loads. so that needs to be corrected first. (Something wrong with dataSource:{data:data}  I think). Another thing once you pushed your new record in data check if its being pushed properly or not because I think you need the extend command too. Below is how I did it
data.push($.extend({},data))
Then you need to set data as the dataSource for scheduler on the click of the button and then update current view with above command.
Hope I've been of some help.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to add an event to the Kendo Scheduler and have it re-render automatically is with the dataSource.add() method.

`$("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler").dataSource.add({your data});`

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/add

Updated example here:
http://dojo.telerik.com/ifeziLiJ

Answer (score 0):

One way to keep the scheduler updated, is by using a SchedulerDataSource, and the setDataSource method of the scheduler (https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler/methods/setdatasource).

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.SchedulerDataSource({
        data: data
    });

$("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler").setDataSource(dataSource);
```